# Spring-Integration-Kafka examples in java 6

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, jdk6

I am a Java newbie and working with spring-integration-kafka, I have been through numerous tutorials like [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/15/using-apache-kafka-for-integration-and-data-processing-pipelines-with-spring).

Are there any examples which use spring-integration-kafka or any other Spring-Integration example for beginners with JDK6.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are newbie in this area you should go through the [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) and go to the [Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka) project.